# How to design a one way cache to keep local files up to date from server

Tags: android, caching, md5, checksum, fileserver

I'm developing an android application that will be using files kept on a server. In specific, these files are maps that the app will present to the user. The files are only likely to change every few months so rather than downloading these files every time the app is launched, I would like to cache them on the device to minimize startup time and network traffic on the server. **What are the best practices to keep the cache files up to date with the files residing on the server? Are there any standard techniques?**

I was thinking of comparing an index of precomputed MD5 checksums. What do you think?

**Update:**
This is a **one way** cache.
The cached files on the device will not edited and uploaded back to the server.

Thanks for the responses! I have never designed a cache before.

Comment: It totally depends on your use case - You can update the cached files every fortnight. Or you can set a flag indicating that a file has changed and needs update.

Comment: In addition it depends on whether the files will be edited on disk or not, and if so whether the changes should be uploaded to the server.  If so, things get a whole lot more complicated, especially if concurrent editing is possible.  If its a one way read only cache, your way is sufficient and a decent solution.